# SQL setting ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to set the `ORDER BY` in a sql statement to the values you want?  For example, if I want to choose the values for Day in this order:  `Thu, Sat, Sun, Mon`

```
SELECT * 
FROM `NFL_Games` 
WHERE Week = '1' 
ORDER BY Day
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use a `case when` clause for personal orderings...

```
order by
(case Day
 when 'Thu' then 1
 when 'Sat' then 2
 when 'Sun' then 3
 when 'Mon' then 4
 else 5 end), 
 Day
```

Comment: Or create a UDF like this

Comment: That looks right, but it gave me some kind of error related to syntax.  HEre is the query:  SELECT * FROM `NFL_Games` WHERE Week = '1' order by
(case Day
 when 'Thu' then 1
 when 'Sat' then 2
 when 'Sun then 3
 when 'Mon' then 4
 else 5 end), 
 Day

Comment: Heres the error:     #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Mon' then 4 else 5 end), Day' at line 5

Comment: You are missing the closing quote at `'Sun`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use expressions in `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT * FROM `NFL_Games` WHERE Week = '1' ORDER BY DAYOFWEEK( date_field )
```

Comment: how would I build the query as I showed above though to order by Thu, Sat, Sun, Mon?

Comment: If you need just "shift" days use this formula: MOD(DAYOFWEEK( date_field ) + 4 ), 6)

Answer (score 0):

As `Order by` is the last clause that is processed while executing a query , yes if your select statement has day column ( either calculated based on date from table 'NFL_Games' or the table has a  column 'Day' you can specify ordering among rows in your final set.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work.. maybe a little annoying because of the case statement but would do the job.

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE fstrDay 
         WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 0 
         WHEN 'Friday' THEN 1 
         WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 2 
         WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 3 
         WHEN 'Monday' THEN 4 
         WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 5 
         WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 6 
       END AS flngOrder 
FROM   NFL_Games
WHERE  Week = '1'
ORDER  BY flngOrder ASC
```

Answer (score -2):

That seems perfectly legit; you can also sort by ascending or descending, depending on your preference.